# Automatically change price when I change inventory in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am creating an invoice form.
I would like to have a function where if I change the inventory (dropdown search), the corresponding price will also change.

You can see an illustration of what I want here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kpyfve3gzxmcls/dj006_ultimate_goal_for_adding_variable_attr.jpg?dl=0

What I know so far is I can I can query the inventory dropdown search through:

```py
inventory = Inventory.objects.get(pk=request.POST['inventory_dropdown_id'])
price = inventory.price
```

But

1. how do I propogate such "get" function throughout all the forms (since I'm using query set)
2. how do I set the price (in the view.py) back to the html file when the html file is already rendered?

Is there away around this?

**P.S.** Probably been asked before here but I couldn't find any reference. (Hard to find what proper keyword to search) So if you want to post a link. I'd be happy to take a look at it.

================================================================

**EDIT: Here is the model structure:**

```py
#MODELS.PY

class Invoice_Test_M2M(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    ref_num = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ref_num

class Inventory_Test_M2M(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    inventory_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    invoice = models.ManyToManyField('Invoice_Test_M2M', through= "Invoice_Inventory_Through")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
         return self.inventory_name


class Invoice_Inventory_Through(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice_Test_M2M, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory_Test_M2M, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

#FORMS.PY

class Invoice_Inventory_ThroughForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice_Inventory_Through
        exclude = ()

Inventory_TestLineItem_M2M_Formset = inlineformset_factory(Invoice_Test_M2M, Invoice_Inventory_Through, form=Invoice_Inventory_ThroughForm, fields = '__all__', exclude = [], can_delete = True)#

#VIEWS.PY
class Invoice_M2M_CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Invoice_Test_M2M
    success_url=reverse_lazy('music:album_list')
    garbage = Invoice_Inventory_ThroughForm
    garbage.price_val = 123
    form = garbage

    fields = '__all__'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Invoice_M2M_CreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['track_formset'] = Inventory_TestLineItem_M2M_Formset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['track_formset'] = Inventory_TestLineItem_M2M_Formset()
        context['price_val'] = 2
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        formset = context['track_formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            response = super().form_valid(form)
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
            return response
        else:
            return super().form_invalid(form
```

Comment: Show your model structure

Comment: Ah gotcha. Sorry for that. Edited the original post now to include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall be done by Ajax and OnChange handler for the select. You create a view that you send it the id of product and it returns the price to ajax call and on the success of ajax you update the value of the price inputfield with the received price.

Comment: @Mohammed 
Thanks for the response and not just down voting it.

Anyway, it's actually what I was looking for. I just search "AJAX and OnChange" and the the results pretty much speak for itself. The most prominent one I use for reference is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDdLvImfq_g&t=806s

It's my first time encountering AJAX so there is no way I would have search it easily. 

Have a great day ahead!